# How does em.flush causes LockAcquisitionException?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm refactoring a code from a project and during my lunch I started looking at some error logs from the application running the old code. It's somehow related to the `EntityManager#flush` method (this project is using Hibernate as the persistence framework).

There's a process that select some X rows (up to 10) from a process and lock them by using `for update` -- `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)`. This is within a transaction boundary and it uses Spring Data JPA Repositories and Spring Transaction Management (`@Transactional`).

I saw the following code (just a representation, since the actual code is huge):

```
@Transactional
public void method() {
    // uses @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    List<Foo> entities = fooRepository.selectForUpdate();
    // iterates all entities, do some work and update them
    for (Foo foo: entities) {
        foo.setX(321);
    }

    // save the list of entities
    fooRepository.saveAll(foo);
    // flush() is causing LockAcquisitionException
    fooRepository.flush();
}
```

By looking at the logs, the line `fooRepository.flush()` is causing a `LockAcquisitionException`. This is really strange to me and I've never saw this before. If the rows were already selected successfully, how do this exception occurs while flushing?

Funny enough, this only happens during high throughputs periods of the day.

A snippet from the StackTrace:

```
org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:287)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy150.flush(Unknown Source)
at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.MyClass.method(MyClass.java:764)
....
```

As per the last line of this snippet, you see that the error occurs on line 764, which is exactly where the flush happens.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and the SQL statements executed.

Answer (score 0):

Without the full stack trace and logs it is impossible to help you. The exception usually indicates a deadlock or lock timeout, so maybe you are flushing something that isn't locked yet. When flushing, MySQL tries to lock the rows in some order and if some other TX acquires locks in a different order, you see a deadlock like this.